# Making a table that keeps logs of updates in mysql

Tags: mysql, updating

I'd like to make a table that will keep track of a separate updating table on a day to day basis.  For example, I have a table currently that keeps track of inventory and once a day I'd like to run a report that gives me information like how many new items were added, how many items were sold etc, and have each of those queries be stored as separate columns in the table.  Is this possible? I've done some research trying to find a solution but haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: you could use some triggers after update or insert on the tables you wish to monitorize

Comment: thanks, I should be able to take it from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- way 1: use database trigger, which could issue an event when you insert/update/delete a line,
- way 2: in your code, like java, keep track of the insert/remove event in a memory counter(you can use spring aop to detect event, and use memory or memcache to keep the numbers), and use a  scheduled program to write the data to a table, and reset them every day,(in java, jdk provide there class, or you can use quartz framework),